# Dynamic SOSL SearchQuery with AND Clause for Contact Firstname and Lastname

Tags: apex, force.com, sosl, dynamic-sosl

If i am trying to make a **SOSL Search Query** dynamic where **Firstname and Lastname** will be coming from **remote parameter dynamically**. Attached code sample is **not working** -

[image]

But if i make the **SOSL Query as hardcode** like below, It works perfectly and gives **appropriate result**.   -

```
searchquery = '';
searchquery = 'FIND {"Jo*" And "Bo*"} IN Name Fields RETURNING Contact(Firstname,Lastname,Title, Account.Name, Phone, Email)';
```

In the above code **"Jo*" is the FirstName** and **"Bo*" is the Lastname**

Comment: Did you try 

searchQuery = 'FIND ' + searchQuery + ' IN Name Fields RETURNING ' etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
searchQuery = 'FIND ' + searchQuery + ' IN Name Fields RETURNING '
```

Please also mark this answer as accepted if this works for you.